# How to understand "<since>" in git format-patch manual?

Tags: git

I am reading the `man` page of `git format-patch`:

> There are two ways to specify which commits to operate on.
>
> 1. A single commit, `<since>`, specifies that the commits leading to the tip of the current branch that are not in the history that leads to the `<since>` to be output.
>
> ......

I am confused to understand "`commits ... that are not in the history that leads to the <since> to be output.`". I think it should be "...that are <del>not</del> in the history ...".

Comment: But wouldn't that include all the history *before* that commit? The wording of that sentence could be different to be clearer but the way I understand it, any commits that are predecessors of `<since>` will not be included in the history, hence it is correct that "not" is part of that sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording may be confusing, because English-language parsing is tricky, but this is what it means:

> A single commit, `<since>`, specifies that
>
> 1. the commits leading to the tip of the current branch
>
> that are not in
>
> 2. the history that leads to the `<since>`
>
> to be output.

To put it in a much more understandable way, start with a graph drawing:

```
______________________________

...--o--o--<since>--o--o--o--o   <-- currentbranch (HEAD)
__________________
```

The part I numbered 2, *the history that leads to the `<since>`*, is the part with the underline.  The part I numbered 1, *the commits leading to the tip of the current branch*, is the part with the overline.  The whole expression amounts to "overlined set, minus underlined set", which leaves commits *after*—and *excluding*—`<since>`, up to and *including* `HEAD`.

This is also what `git rev-list` (and therefore `git log`) means when you write:

```
<since>..HEAD
```

Note that if the history has branches, the result can be a bit surprising:

```
...--o--o--*--*--*--*---*   <-- currentbranch (HEAD)
         \             /
          o--<since>--*
```

In this case, the commits included by `<since>..currentbranch` are those marked with `*`.  This is *not* special to `git format-patch`: it applies to *all* commit-graph-based operations when you use the syntax spelled `<since>..currentbranch` or `<since>..HEAD` or `<since>..` (all three of these mean the same thing).

(Possibly confusingly, `git diff` *doesn't* do commit-graph-based operations, so if you try to base your understanding on how `git diff` behaves, you will *won't* see this effect.  The one command most people *do* use a lot that *does* see this effect is `git log` itself—but since `git log` does not draw the graph by default, it's not obvious what's going on.  To make it obvious, get help from a/the DOG: `git log --decorate --oneline --graph <since>..HEAD`.  Logs, or sticks for that matter, are always more fun with a **D**ecorate **O**neline **G**raph. :-)